# Interlace wordpress customs query

Tags: php, wordpress

I want display post on my wordpress home page in this order:

sticky0 normal0 normal1 normal2 stycky1 normal3 normal4 normal5

to do that I suppose that I need to use two [customs query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

The problem is not [the query to get sticky post and to get normal post without stycky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18400405/show-sticky-posts-at-the-top-then-display-other-posts), but the procedure to interlace the [loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your theme index.php:

```
<?php if( have_posts() ): ?>

<?php
    $stickies = array();
    $query = new WP_Query( *args* );
    if( false !== $query ) {
        $stickies = $query->get_posts();
    }
    $i = 0;
    $i2 = 0;

    while( have_posts() ){
        if( isset( $stickies[$i2] ) && ($i == 0 || $i == 3) ){
            // display your sticky
            setup_postdata($stickies[$i2]);
            get_template_part('content', 'sticky');
            $i2++;
        } else {
            // display normal post
            the_post();
            get_template_part('content', get_post_type());
        }
        i++;
    }
?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Found [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/126346/resetting-post-data-to-previous-loop-in-nested-loops)